# SMJobBless returns error 5

Tags: macos

My call to `SMJobBless()` is returning error 5 (kSMErrorToolNotValid), even though `SMJobBlessUtil.py check` doesn't find any problems. (It did initially, and I resolved them all)

SMJobBlessUtil checks a lot of stuff, including:

- Code singing on app and tool, including checking designated requirements
- info.plists refer to each other correctly
- Label field in launchd.plist is correct

What else could cause it to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it just turns out I was referring to my tool by the wrong name. So the "not valid" error can also mean "not found".